# Kendo ScrollView - Refresh/redraw current page

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using a Kendo ScrollView to display person images on a form.

Separate from the ScrollView, users can change the display order of the images. After they save their changes to the display order, the ScrollView is reloaded, scrolls to the first item, and *should* display the images in their new order.

However, I've noticed that when the ScrollView is currently on the first page, that page does not get refreshed/redrawn.

My ScrollView looks something like this:

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().ScrollView()
    .Name("personImage")
    .TemplateId("personImageTemplate")
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Custom()
        .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
        .Transport(t => t
            .Read(r => r.Action("PersonImages_Read", "Person", new { personID = Model.ID } ))
        )
        .Schema(s => s.Data("Data").Total("Total"))
        .ServerPaging(false)
        .PageSize(1)
    )
)
```

The template looks like this:

```html
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="personImageTemplate">
    <img class="personImage" 
         src="@(Url.Action("ImageRender", "Person"))?imageID=#= data.ID #"
         title="#= data.Filename #" />
</script>
```

And here is my refresh function:

```js
function refreshPersonImageScrollView() {
    var scrollView = $("#personImage").data("kendoScrollView");
    if (scrollView) {
        scrollView.dataSource.read();

        // https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scrollview/methods/refresh
        // redraws, doesn't re-read from datasource
        scrollView.refresh();
        
        // scroll to first image
        scrollView.scrollTo(0);
    }
}
```

When I watch the requests being made when I call this function, I see this:

A. When a page *other than* the first page is selected:

1. `PersonImages_Read` (the ScrollView's `dataSource` read)
2. The ScrollView scrolls to the first image
3. 3x `ImageRender`, as it renders the first 3 items in the ScrollView

B. When the first page is selected:

1. `PersonImages_Read` (the ScrollView's `dataSource` read)
2. Nothing else

I tried switching the order of `scrollView.refresh()` and `scrollView.scrollTo(0)`, but the result does not change.

Is there any way to get Kendo to refresh/redraw the current page? I thought `refresh` would do it, based on the documentation, but it does not.

#### Edit

I've been able to replicate this issue in [REPL](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/mmbcYVGc41goxSJE29). To see the behavior in action:

1. Note the "Rendered" time under the first image.
2. Scroll to the second image in the ScrollView.
3. Wait several seconds, then click the "Refresh" button.
   The ScrollView should scroll back to the first image.
4. Observe that the "Rendered" time under the first image matches the "Last clicked" time reported below the "Refresh" button, and is no longer what it was in step #1. (This is the correct behavior.)
5. Remain on the first image for several seconds. Note the "Rendered" time listed before continuing.
6. Click the "Refresh" button.
7. Note that the "Last clicked" time has updated, and in the "Log" section, there is an entry that reads "dataSource read complete" at approx. the same time. However, the "Rendered" time under the image has not changed, and there is no log entry that says "image for product #X loaded".

I am using Kendo version **2021.3.1109** in my project. The Kendo version in the REPL above is **2022.3.913** and it still occurs in that version.

Comment: What happens with the scrollView.refresh() call if you use the code from the Telerik refresh link to set the scrollView var - any difference? Their example explicitly enables the pager - var scrollView = $("#scrollView").kendoScrollView({ enablePager: true}).data().kendoScrollView;

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. This part: `$("#personImage").kendoScrollView({ enablePager: true })` makes it try to re-initialize the existing scrollview, and really messes up the display. Even then, the refresh doesn't re-render the current page.  
Adding `.EnablePager(true)` to the definition in razor doesn't fix it either.

Comment: do you think you could get the issue replicated in REPL on the Telerik site?https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/cGlQEVcF05uVCSU225

Comment: @G_P I was able to replicate the behavior, and have edited my question to include a link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to resolve the issue, but this may be worth opening a possible bug ticket with Telerik, because you would think that scrollView.refresh call would work.

What I changed in your refreshPersonImageScrollview function was to call setDataSource on the scrollview rather than calling the refresh method. Like so:

```
function refreshPersonImageScrollView() {
    $("#refresh-last-clicked").text("Last clicked: " + getCurrentTime());
    addToLog("refresh button clicked");

    var scrollView = $("#personImage").data("kendoScrollView");
    if (scrollView) {
        scrollView.dataSource.read();
        
        scrollView.setDataSource(scrollView.dataSource);

        // scroll to first image
        scrollView.scrollTo(0);
    }
}
```

This appears to force the scrollView to re-evaluate its life choices and properly refresh :)  However, it does seem to trigger additional dataSource reads, so it's not ideal.

One other thing I tried that didn't resolve the problem, but may be a good thing to change to anyway, would be to utilize the promise returned by the dataSource.read call. Meaning, do your scrollView setDataSource and scrollTo calls after the dataSource read promise is settled, like so:

```
scrollView.dataSource.read().then(function() {
    scrollView.setDataSource(scrollView.dataSource);
                
    // scroll to first image
    scrollView.scrollTo(0);
});
```

[REPL link here](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/mcFmaCPA22AjtgXo42)